# How to populate Websphere Dynacache in pre-integration-test phase?

Tags: java, maven, caching, websphere, dbunit

I'm using Maven to run integration tests with JUnit in a multimodule project. However, these testcases rely on data that needs to be in Websphere cache to work. I'm using DBUnit to do INSERT operations on pre-integration-test via Antrun plugin, but the integration tests run AFTER the server warm-up, so Websphere cache is empty, because it tried to populate on warm-up but there was no data in database.

Nowadays, we're inserting data on cache via Java code. My idea is to abstract that from code, and put it to work using a Maven plugin. Is that possible? How do I do that?

Comment: How and where you start up WebSphere?

Comment: I start Websphere 7 locally via WAS6 Maven plugin.